# Why is one algorithm faster than another with the same time complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I was working on a codingame challenge : the horse racing dual.
The goal is to find the minimum difference between two elements of a list.

I started with this first algorithm, which is i think in `O(nlog(n))` but the execution was timing out for large arrays.

```cpp
int array[N];
int min = numeric_limits<int>::max();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  int value;
  cin >> value;
  cin.ignore();
  array[i] = value;

  for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
    int diff = abs(array[j] - value);
    if (diff < min) {
      min = diff;
    }
  }
}
```

I then tried this other algorithm which is also `O(nlog(n))`and this time the execution finishes in time.

```cpp
int array[N];
int min = numeric_limits<int>::max();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  int value;
  cin >> value;
  cin.ignore();
  array[i] = value;
}

sort(array, array + N);

for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
  int diff = abs(array[i - 1] - array[i]);
  if (diff < min) {
    min = diff;
  }
}
```

Am I wrong with the first code complexity ? Is there any difference that I did not notice ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read much more about [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity): two algorithms could both be *O(n log n)* and the first might be 10x faster than the second on any *reasonably sized* input

Comment: The complexity of the first algorithm isn't _O(n log n)_ but _O(n^2)_.

Comment: Time complexity isn't about *speed*. As the name suggests, it's about *complexity*

Comment: time complexity is a rather broad measure of performance. When two algorithms have the same time complexity, it doesn't mean they are equally fast, it only means their execution time _scales_ very similar

Comment: Are you aware that O(n) == O(1000n) == O(1000n + 1000)?

Comment: Even if the complexity is the same, consider if you clone an algorithm and put a `sleep(1)` inside the clone. It still has the same complexity but will be very slow compared to the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I understand my misconception about time complexity.
However, why is my first program in O(n^2) as I only compare one value with the previous ones ?

Comment: complexity is about asymptotic behavior. An `O(1)` algorithm can take longer than `O(n)` for any realistic value of `n` if just the constant is big enough (remember that `O(1) == O( some_constant)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong with the first code complexity?

Yes, you are wrong, this complexity is not *O(n log n)*, but *O(n^2)* instead.

The outer loop runs *n* (`N`) times while the inner loop runs *n/2* times in average. Thus, the complexity is *O(n * n/2)* which is *O(n^2)*, since multiplicative constants doesn't matter in complexity calculations.

> Is there any difference that I did not notice?

Yes, there is. Even if you have two algorithms with the very same complexity, such as *O(n log n)*, they both can run in very different times due to hidden constants, which are ignored in asymptotic complexity behavior.